# How to import/use an external JavaScript file in the background script of a Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

Inside the background script of my WebExtension I want to use functions/constants from another JavaScript file. But as simple as it sounds, I cannot get it to work.

I'm using the following four files as a minimal example for my problem:

1. `manifest.json`:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "MinimalCompleteReproducibleExample",
       "version": "0.0.0.0",

       "background": {
           "page": "background.html"
       }
   }
   ```

   It basically just loads `background.html` as the background script/page.
2. `background.html`:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
       </head>
       <body>
           <script type="module" src="/mylib.js"></script>
           <script src="background.js"></script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

   It loads the "external" JavaScript file `mylib.js` that contains the functions/constants I want to reuse and the actual background script `background.js`.
3. `mylib.js`:

   ```js
   export const foo = 42;
   ```

   It just exports the constant `foo`.
4. `background.js`:

   ```js
   console.log(foo);
   ```

   It tries to use the content of the "external" JavaScript file `mylib.js`.

When I load this extension, I get the following error message in the debugger:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

That seems to indicate that the content of `mylib.js` is not available.

Before that, I did load the `background.js` directly in `manifest.json` and added the following line to `background.js`:

```js
import { foo } from "/mylib.js";
```

But that does not seem to be allowed in WebExtensions and also does not work:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

So can someone tell me, how to make another JavaScript file available inside a background script?

Comment: Add `type="module"` to your background script declaration as well.

Comment: Please note that using a remote script in a Firefox extension will result in rejection of the extension by AMO.

Comment: @erosman Thanks for the advice. Fortunateley, I don't plan to pull it in dynamically. I will ship the library within the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wOxxOm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619663/how-to-import-use-an-external-javascript-file-in-the-background-script-of-a-fire#comment112500147_63619663) helped me solving it. Two changes are necessary:

- Addition of `type="module"` to `<script src="background.js"></script>` in `background.html`
- Addition of `import { foo } from "/mylib.js";` to `background.js`

The line `<script type="module" src="/mylib.js"></script>` in `background.html` can then be omitted.

Complete working example:

1. `manifest.json`:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "MinimalCompleteReproducibleExample",
       "version": "0.0.0.0",

       "background": {
           "page": "background.html"
       }
   }
   ```
2. `background.html`:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
       </head>
       <body>
           <script type="module" src="/background.js"></script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. `mylib.js`:

   ```js
   export const foo = 42;
   ```
4. `background.js`:

   ```js
   import { foo } from "/mylib.js";
   console.log(foo);
   ```